# Flask - use javascript to display loading page while waiting for task to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

In `menu.html`, a click on an given link renders the chosen page, `pasta.html`, in this fashion:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('pasta') }}";>Pasta</a>
            <form action="{{ url_for('handle_menu') }}" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="additive" value="Cheese"> <label style="font-size: 11px;">Cheese</label>
            </form>
      </li>
```

but let's say `@app.route('/pasta')` has to 'cook' some 'ingredients' before it's 'done':

```
 @app.route('/pasta')
 def pasta():

     # (perform some long task here)

     return render_template('pasta.html')
```

for that matter I would like to display a `/cooking` view while the page loads, like so:

```
@app.route('/cooking')
def cooking():
    return render_template('cooking.html')
```

---

If I'm not mistaken, with `Flask` and `jinja2` templates you either return (`200`) or redirect (`301`) a page, and for any intermediate page like `loading.html`, you need `javascript`.

---

**So, how can I use `javascript` here in order to display `cooking.html` page *while* waiting for `/pasta` task to complete, and *once the task is done*, finally return it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using a **GET** request, you can have your anchor tag route to `cooking`, render the `cooking.html` template, then use `window.location.replace()` to redirect to `pasta`. The long task in `pasta()` will be performed before `pasta.html` is rendered.

In `menu.html`:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('cooking') }}">Pasta</a>
```

In `cooking.html`:

```
<script> window.location.replace('/pasta'); </script>
```

---

In the case of a **POST** request, you would need to send the form values to `cooking`, pass them to the template, then send them again to `pasta` using AJAX, and finally redirect in the callback function.

In `menu.html`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('cooking') }}" method='POST'>
```

In `cooking()`:

```
@app.route('/cooking')
def cooking():
    return render_template('cooking.html', form_data=request.form['form_data'])
```

In `pasta()`:

```
@app.route('/pasta', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pasta():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        render_template('pasta.html')

    # (perform some long task here)

    return make_response('POST request successful', 200)
```

In `cooking.html`:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/pasta',
        data: {
            form_data: '{{form_data}}',
        },
        success: function() {
            window.location.replace('/pasta');
        }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: If you are working with blueprints, remember to put its url_prefix on `<script> window.location.replace('<url_prefix>/pasta'); </script> `.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a third endpoint called **cooking_request**:

1. `/cooking_request`
2. `/cooking`
3. `/pasta`

Render the `/cooking_request` page and have javascript in there to call the `/cooking` page using Ajax. When `/cooking` responds, you'll then request the `/pasta` contents and display to the user.

Here's an example code you could use in your `/cooking_request` page. It will call the `/cooking` page, wait for it and finally render `/pasta` inside the div#pasta-results element.

```
<div id="pasta-results">Please wait, loading...</div>

<script type="text-javascript">
    function loadPasta() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("pasta-results").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://website-host/pasta", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function loadCooking() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          loadPasta();
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://website-host/cooking", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    loadCooking();
<script>
```

Comment: but `/pasta` is rendered only after task is complete...won't I have to wait anyway? I'd like a solution for while task is being performed before rendering.

Comment: I edited the example in my response to load `/cooking` first, then `/pasta`. Since your `/cooking` takes time (as you said), your user will have to wait for it at some point. Unless you improve your code performance to make it faster. But your question was about how to load content dynamically from Javascript. that's what I answered...

Comment: ok, but where does this first rendering (`/cooking_request`) takes place? where is the action? I start clicking at a link `<a href="{{ url_for('pasta') }}`. I'd have to change it to `{{ url_for('cooking_request) }}`?

Comment: Correct. You can name each endpoint whatever you want though. It's only to demonstrate you in simple terms how you could use JavaScript to load content and display on the user interface.